# Art supplies for a mathematician

Tags: soft-question

These days the best tool for visualizing math is probably a computer.  Nevertheless, I find it helpful/fun/nice-break-from-the-computer to sometimes make physical objects or drawings by hand.  The most basic tools are of course a pen and paper, and a lot can be done with just this, especially if you start folding.  Here are some other basic supplies I keep in my office:

- Colored pencils/pens
- Cardstock
- String
- Thumbtacks
- Compass
- Straightedge
- Protractor
- Tape
- Scissors

What are some other supplies that are useful to have around?

Comment: https://www.zometool.com/ I'm the only one on my block with a 42-sided semi-regular, um, thing. It's pretty strong, too, the center is an icosahedron with radii out of a central node. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamfered_dodecahedron

Comment: Spirograph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph

Comment: I am in the business for 50 years, and i use sometimes compasses protractors, strings, tape and scissors, for my OTHER activities, but do not remember ever using anything in your list for mathematics. Except paper, ballpens and computer. So I would not call them "supplies for a mathematician". On the other hand, your list does not include such crucial supplies as chalk and blackboard:-)

Comment: Related: [Where to buy premium white chalk in the U.S., like they have at RIMS?](//mathoverflow.net/q/26267) and [Good chalk in the UK](//mathoverflow.net/q/58168).

Comment: Related: [What's so great about blackboards?](//mathoverflow.net/q/5936)

Answer (score 0):

On page 183 of his book Cubic Forms, in the bibliographical remarks to the section on the twenty-seven lines, Manin quotes Henderson's historical summary:

> Indeed Sylvester once remarked, in his characteristical florid style:
> "Surely with as good reason as had Archimedes to have the cylinder,
> cone, and sphere engraved on his tombstone might our distinguished
> countrymen leave testamentary directions for the cubic eikosiheptagram
> to be engraved on theirs."
>
> If Cayley and Salmon had wished to follow Sylvester's advice and to
> insert a clause in their wills, directing that an eikosiheptagram be
> engraved upon their monuments, they would have had no certainty of the
> correct fulfilment of their directions until the year 1869, when
> Christian Wiener made a model of a cubic surface showing twenty-seven
> real lines lying upon it. This achievement of Wiener, Sylvester once
> remarked, is one of the discoveries "which must for ever make 1869
> stand out in the Annals of Science."
>
> Klein exhibited a complete set of models of cubic surfaces at the
> World's Exposition in Chicago in 1894, including Clebsch's symmetrical
> model of the diagonal surface and Klein's model of the cubic surface
> having four real conical points. Models of the typical cases of all
> the principal forms of cubic surfaces have been constructed by
> Rodenberg for Brill's collections; and these plaster models may now be
> purchased.

Manin concludes: "Henderson's book appeared in 1911. Sylvester's eloquence and the plaster models disappeared together with the Victorian era... "